# Replace comma between two characters

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a txt file and I need to replace comma with space only between quotation marks.

For example:

```
This,is,example,"need,delete comma",xxxx
```

And the result should be:

```
This,is,example,"need delete comma",xxxx
```

I have this command, but it's wrong:

```
sed -i '/^"/,/^"/s/.,/ /' output.txt
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to replace the commas? Are you trying to work around not having a proper CSV parser?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> awk 'NR%2-1{gsub(/,/," ")}1' RS=\" ORS=\" input.txt > output.txt

Input:

> This,is,example,"need,delete comma",xxxx

Output:

> This,is,example,"need delete comma",xxxx

Comment: this will add trailing `"` at the end of the multiline output. You may test on the `testfile` from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118785/replace-comma-between-two-characters/46119331#46119331

Answer (score 0):

Complex ***awk*** solution:

Sample `testfile`:

```
This,is,example,"need,delete comma",xxxx
asda
asd.dasd,asd"sdf,dd","sdf,sdfsdf"
"some,text,here" another text there""
```

---

The job:

```
awk -F'"' '$0~/"/ && NF>1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(!(i%2)) gsub(/,/," ",$i) }}1' OFS='"' testfile
```

The output:

```
This,is,example,"need delete comma",xxxx
asda
asd.dasd,asd"sdf dd","sdf sdfsdf"
"some text here" another text there""
```

Answer (score 0):

how about the following awk, where I am looking for only match between "..." and then simply removing all commas in that match. Then replace the new values of it with old ".." values.

```
awk '{match($0,/\".*\"/);val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/,/," ",val);gsub(/\".*\"/,val,$0)} 1'  Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** After seeing RomanPerekhrest's Input_file a little change in above code which will prohibit to change "," in any line.

```
awk '{match($0,/\".*\"/);val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/[^","],/," ",val);gsub(/\".*\"/,val,$0)} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

echo 'This,is,example,"need,delete comma",xxxx' |awk -F\" '{sub(/,/," ",$2); print}' OFS=\"

This,is,example,"need delete comma",xxxx